# Generate tlb from dll in same directory under another name

Tags: dll, tlb

I want to make a type lib (tlb) having another name than dll:

```
c:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\regasm.exe "c:\program files (x86)\sample_program\Library.dll" "c:\program files (x86)\sample_program\TypeLibname.tlb" /codebase
```

When executing this line in Powershell, no errors occur.

> Microsoft .NET Framework Assembly Registration Utility 4.7.3056.0
>   für Microsoft .NET Framework, Version 4.7.3056.0
>   [...]
>   Types have been registered

So a tlb must have been generated. Though the tlb is put everywhere, but not in the desired directory "c:\program files (x86)\sample_program\"

Any idea ?

Thank you !

All the best,
Stephan

Comment: The command is not correct.  Type regasm.exe /? to get usage guidance.

Comment: see my answer below. Missing switch was /tlb to generate the type lib.

Answer (score 0):

Just had to insert /tlb and change the expression into:

c:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\regasm.exe "c:\program files (x86)\sample_program\Library.dll" /tlb:TypeLibname.tlb /codebase